# jquery and styles inside a Live Link

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I having some trouble trying to work with WordPress and live links.

Let me explain :

I have this link in the category called:

```
<a href="p?32" id="control">event 32</a>
```

event 32 is manage by this code:

```
  $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});


  $('#control').click(function(){
    var post_id = $(this).attr('href')

    $('#calendar').animate({top:'-99em'},400,
      function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('#theEvent').fadeIn(400);
        $('#theEvent').html('<div class="loading"></div>');
        $('#theEvent').load(post_id);
      });
    return false;

  });
```

and this works perfectly , the content of this single is shown:

a this is the single.php:

```
<div class="space"></div>
<div class="clearfix">

    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <div class="descritpion">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <span><?php the_author(); ?></span>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <div class="center">
     <a href=# id="prev">Prev</a>
     <a href=# id="next">Next</a>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="gallery" >
  <a href="/#fourth" id="close" class="close">X</a>

  <div id="slideShow">
    <?php the_gallery(); ?>

  </div>
```

the function `the_gallery()` is just a loop of images with a link : `<a rel="fancybox"><img/></a>`

> Edit: 06.09.12

the gallery function works with [attachments-plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/attachments/)

```
function the_gallery() {

    $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
    $total_attachments = count($attachments);

    if( $total_attachments > 0 )
    {
        for ($i=0; $i < $total_attachments; $i++)

        {
            $url =  wp_get_attachment_image( $attachments[$i]['id'],
                'bullet-event');
            $lrgurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachments[$i]['id'], 'large' );




            echo '

            <a href="'.$lrgurl[0].'"
            rel="#overlay" title="'.$attachments[$i]['title'].'">
            ' . $url . '
            </a> ';


        }
    }

}
```

the jquery inside the single .php is:

```
var wrapEveryN = function(n, elements, wrapper) {
    for (var i=0; i< elements.length; i+=n) {
        elements.slice(i,i+n).wrapAll(wrapper);
    }
}

wrapEveryN( 12, $("#slideShow a"), '<div></div>' );

$('#slideShow').cycle({
    fx:     'scrollLeft'
});
```

The problem comes here, inside the single I have to manage a image gallery (cycle) a fancybox and styles... the only thing that shows correctly are the styles but I don't know why the js is not working:

al my codes and plugins are in `plugins.php` & `main.php`

Comment: Show us your js code (for gallery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your js code is in a ready block, so it won't be executed 2 times.

Try this for example :

```
$('#theEvent').load(post_id, function(){
  wrapEveryN( 12, $("#slideShow a"), '<div></div>' );

  $('#slideShow').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft';
  });
});
```

PS : you should load only [page fragment](http://api.jquery.com/load/)